# Swift XMLParser in Playground - Delegate Deallocated

Tags: swift, xml, swift-playground

This code snippet is from a demo for working with XML files in Swift. Since this code is executed from playground following image shows the project structure.

[image: swift playground files]

The XMLapp file contains the `class XMLapp`. This class contains a nested `class XMLreader: NSObject, XMLParserDelegate`. Since the `XMLapp` class is created in playground, it contains static function to call the code for reading XML.

```
public static func readXML() {
    print("readXML")
    let xmlReader = XMLreader()
    xmlReader.parse()
}
```

Inside the main playground, following call is made `XMLapp.readXML()`, which has this output:

```
readXML
begin parsing
end parsing
```

import Foundation

```
public class XMLapp {

    class XMLreader: NSObject, XMLParserDelegate {

        var xmlParser: XMLParser {
            let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource:"sample.xml",withExtension:nil)!
            return XMLParser(contentsOf: url)!
        }

        public func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, foundElementDeclarationWithName elementName: String, model: String) {
            print("element name: \(elementName), model: \(model)")
        }
        
        public func parserDidStartDocument(_ parser: XMLParser) {
            print("parserDidStartDocument")
        }
        
        public func parserDidEndDocument(_ parser: XMLParser) {
            print("parserDidEndDocument")
        }
        
        // ...
        // other protocol methods
        
        public func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String] = [:]) {
            print("didStartElement")
        }

        public func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {
            print("didEndElement")
        }
        
        // ...
        // other protocol methods

        public override init() {
            super.init()
            xmlParser.delegate = self
        }

        public func parse() {
            print("begin parsing")
            xmlParser.parse()
            print("end parsing")
        }
    }

    public static func readXML() {
        print("readXML")
        let xmlReader = XMLreader()
        xmlReader.parse()
    }
}
```

The callbacks are not getting called. Even though the delegate for the xmlParser is initialized. Please has anybody come across this issue in playground before? The following call is made to assign the delegate, still it is not working as expected.

`xmlParser.delegate = self`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `xmlParser` property in `XMLreader` is a computed property. This means that `return XMLParser(contentsOf: url)!` gets evaluated every time you access it, so you get a new instance every time. As a result, the instance of `XMLParser` you set the `delegate` is a different instance from which you have called `parse`:

```
xmlParser.delegate = self // you get one instance here
xmlParser.parse() // and a different instance here
```

To fix this, you can make `xmlParser` a stored property:

```
let xmlParser: XMLParser = {
    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource:"sample.xml",withExtension:nil)!
    return XMLParser(contentsOf: url)!
}()
```

Notice the `=`. Learn more about the difference in syntax [here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html).

Another way is to assign the `xmlParser` to a local, set the delegate, and then `parse`. This way you ensure that you are working with the same instance:

```
let parser = xmlParser
parser.delegate = self
parser.parse()
```

Comment: updated! the property is updated to being a stored property

Comment: It works and this is now the accepted answer :) Just a quick question, why do the same calls do not work inside `DispatchQueue.main.async`, code here: https://swiftfiddle.com/muv7mimg4ndgre7qnlxkzrsvyi

Comment: @PattMehta The problem with that is that the `xmlReader` instance you created in `readXML` gets deallocated as soon as `readXML` returns. When the async block runs, it's gone already, so you get `async`, `false` and `end parsing` printed. One simple way to get the expected behaviour is to make that a global or `static let` instead. Do note that it doesn't seem to work on swiftfiddle.com, perhaps due to a platform-dependent issue, or just the way that their servers are running your code. This does work in Xcode playgrounds though.

Comment: tested in playground, the output works expected, upvoted comment!